# Como trazer uma Lista em uma consulta JPQL com construtor

Tags: java, query, jpql

Boa tarde,

Estou fazendo uma consulta jpql para trazer um VO(Value Object) com algumas informações, sendo uma delas um `List`. Esta lista está no objeto opCambio, no entanto, está me retornando este erro:

Log:

```
[ERROR] - 01/04/2017 19:16:26 - RuntimeException on EJB call
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [br.com.domain.relatorios.iof.vo.RelatorioIOFOrdemDePagamentoOperacaoCambioVO] [SELECT NEW br.com.domain.relatorios.iof.vo.RelatorioIOFOrdemDePagamentoOperacaoCambioVO(lp, opCambio.id, opCambio.dataRegistro) FROM br.com.domain.ordempagamento.OrdemDePagamentoOperacaoCambio opCambio  JOIN FETCH opCambio.liquidacoesParciais WHERE opCambio.tipoOperacaoCambioOrdemPagamento = :pTipoOperacao  AND opCambio.empresa = :pEmpresa  AND opCambio.situacao in (:pSituacoes)  AND doc.principal = :pPrincipal  AND opCambio.tipoOperacaoCambioOrdemPagamento = :pTipo AND opCambio.tipoAquisicao = :pTipoAquisicaoOrdemDePagamento AND opCambio.dataPrevistaMoedaNacionalBoleto >= :pDataInicial AND opCambio.dataPrevistaMoedaNacionalBoleto < :pDataFinal AND taxa.iof != :pTaxa]
```

Consulta:

```
StringBuffer jpqlClausulaFrom = new StringBuffer("SELECT NEW " + RelatorioIOFOrdemDePagamentoOperacaoCambioVO.class.getName());
    jpqlClausulaFrom.append("(opCambio.liquidacoesParciais, opCambio.id, opCambio.dataRegistro)");
    jpqlClausulaFrom.append(" FROM OrdemDePagamentoOperacaoCambio opCambio ");
```

Construtor:

```
public RelatorioIOFOrdemDePagamentoOperacaoCambioVO(List<LiquidacaoParcialOrdemDePagamento> listaLiquidacoes, Long id, Date dataRegistroOperacao) {
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Coloque mais códigos para que possamos entender o problema, como por exemplo um trecho de que instancia essa classe.

Comment: Bom dia, entao, estou tentando passar para um VO (Value Object) informações provenientes de uma consulta, uma dessas informações é uma lista. O construtor que eu passei ai em cima, é da classe do meu VO. Na minha consulta, eu dou um new na minha classe e passo os campos que eu quero trazer da consulta para criar o VO, no caso, para o List, esta me retornando esse erro "Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class". Os códigos mais relevantes, são os que eu postei na duvida. Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Answer (score 0):

O problema provavelmente é que na consulta JPQL você especifica uma variável `lp` que não está mencionada na consulta JPQL.

Para corrigir, você pode gerar um novo `JOIN` com o alias `lp`:

```
JOIN opCambio.liquidacoesParciais lp
```

E remover o:

```
JOIN FETCH opCambio.liquidacoesParciais
```

Pois não vejo muito sentido em fazer um `FETCH` dele na `opCambio` se você não retorna a entidade `opCambio` no `SELECT`.

Answer (score -2):

Acredito que seu problema seja devido a um mal entendido de como uma query é mapeada para um tipo definido pelo usuário.

A grosso modo, quando você faz uma consulta em um banco de dados, sua query pode retornar:

1. nenhum resultado
2. uma única linha de uma coluna
3. uma única linha de mais de uma coluna
4. mais de uma linha de uma coluna
5. mais de uma linha de mais de uma coluna

Para simplificar nossa discussão, vamos supor que cada coluna na consulta corresponda a um tipo básico de dado: inteiros, strings, decimais etc.

Para empocatar seu resultado em um tipo definido pelo usuário, no seu caso `RelatorioIOFOrdemDePagamentoOperacaoCambioVO`, cada coluna de sua query corresponde a um tipo básico do Java (Integer, Long, Float, String etc).

Portanto, quando você executa o [método](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/persistence/3.1/apidocs/jakarta.persistence/jakarta/persistence/query#getResultList()) `jakarta.persistence.Query#getResultList`, o provedor de persistência vai, linha a linha, transformar o tipo da coluna no tipo Java correspondente e mapeá-lo à propriedade do objeto que está sendo criado. Esse mapeamento é feito de forma escalar. Cada linha da query será transformada em um objeto da lista resultante.

Seu problema é que você está tentando criar um objeto que recebe como parâmetro um vetor e dois tipos escalares. Considerando as possibilidades de retorno enumeradas anteriormente, não é possível fazer isso.

Se você executar a mesma query diretamente na base de dados, o resultado apresentado seria algo como:

| Cambio ID | Data | Operação ID | Operação Desc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-05-08 | 123 | abc |
| 1 | 2023-05-08 | 456 | efg |
| 1 | 2023-05-08 | 789 | hij |

De acordo com o exemplo, seu código espera que o provedor de persistência entenda que o resultado da segunda e da terceira linha (descartando a primeira e a segunda coluna) devem ser mapeados para um tipo específico e, além disso, agrupados em uma lista.

Uma forma de você resolver seu problema aproveitando a estrutura de sua query é criar um tipo que possa ser mapeado coluna a coluna. E, só depois disso, faça uma [redução](https://www.baeldung.com/java-stream-reduce) da sua lista com os agrupadores que lhe interessam.